# DNS issue with Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm trying to point a subdomain journal.mydomain.com to my Heroku app.  I have added the domain with `heroku domains:add journal.mydomain.com` and set the appropriate CNAME record as advised in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains.  However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.  When I access journal.mydomain.com in my browser, it works sometimes but usually just loads mydomain.com instead.  When I run `host journal.mydomain.com`, I get:

```
 % host journal.mydomain.com
journal.mydomain.com has address XX.XX.XX.XX
journal.mydomain.com is an alias for adeel-journal.herokuapp.com.
adeel-journal.herokuapp.com is an alias for ar.herokuapp.com.
ar.herokuapp.com is an alias for argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
journal.adeel.ru is an alias for adeel-journal.herokuapp.com.
adeel-journal.herokuapp.com is an alias for ar.herokuapp.com.
ar.herokuapp.com is an alias for argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

The first line seems to be the issue (XX.XX.XX.XX is the IP address of course).  Is it possible that somehow the wildcard record is conflicting with the CNAME record?  If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've accidentally created both `A` and `CNAME` records for `journal.adeel.ru` - which would explain the flaky behaviour.

Remove the A record and just use the CNAME - although it looks like you may have resolved it, as this is what I see from my end:

```
matt@indianajones:~$ host journal.adeel.ru
journal.adeel.ru is an alias for adeel-journal.herokuapp.com.
adeel-journal.herokuapp.com is an alias for ar.herokuapp.com.
```

I am also definitely hitting your Heroku app, judging by the headers sent back from curl.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to have fixed itself.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Well it wasn’t actually fixed, but I just ended up switching DNS providers and now it’s fine.